# Unable to test my camera for a Face detection Code

Tags: python, opencv

#This is the Code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera")
    exit()
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # if frame is read correctly ret is True
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break
    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv.imshow('frame', gray)
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

[The attached screenshot is the error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzfA9.png)

Do note that It should start capturing the live video from the webcam and NOT from any stored video footage or Image.
Thank you for your Time.

Comment: do you have a camera? most importantly if yes, are there any other apps using it while you run your code?

Comment: Yes,I have a inbuilt camera in my laptop,and I have even tried to run the code keeping all files and programs closed.Still I am facing the same issue.

Comment: That's weird, usually `VideoCapture(0)` is the in-built camera

Comment: Does the camera actually work, with other applications?

Comment: Yes,I have checked it's working with other applications and online webcam tests as well.Everything is working fine.Lemme try updating the camera drivers if any.Meanwhile do suggest something to figure it out.

Comment: The problem has been resolved by changing the camera index.Thank you everyone for the valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment, so I'll put this as answer.

The error signifies potential issues:

1. The camera you try to open is in use. Check that it isn't used by other applications.
2. Driver issue. Update the camera driver.
3. Camera permissions. Ensure permission is granted.
4. Incorrect camera index. Try opening cameras in range(1,5), perhaps. It'll give you more info
5. Hardware issue. Did you check that the camera actually works? Open google meet or something to prompt it.

Comment: I tried all of the cases and luckily the 4th point i.e changing camera index worked in my case.
Thank you very much.